# Prefill form through URL with square brackets in field name

Tags: html

I'm trying to fill a table in a webpage using a URL.  The problem is the field name that I want to populate has square brackets, which are invalid URL characters.  I've tried replacing [  with %5B and ] with %5D, but the fields still do not populate.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

```
http://www.url.com/index.php?var[1][1]=1&var[1][2]=16
```

I want to give people a link to a URL with populated fields.  I don't own the website so I can't change the field names.  Is there an alternative way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Can you give more information on the purpose and goal of this?  You say you're trying to provide a link for users where the forms on the destination page are pre-filled, but you've not provided a link to the site.

Comment: I want to prepopulate the table on this [site](http://foodclub.daqtools.info/Bets_Dropdown.php).  Currently, I provide a text table and users go to the site and fill out the form manually, and click "Submit" to view the results.  The goal is to eliminate the manual input.

Comment: Do you know for fact that the site is expecting a GET request? The URL variables don't directly translate into form variables unless someone on the server side wrote code to make it do so.

Comment: I've confirmed that the site accepts form parameters in the URL, since setting the 'safety' form is allowed. It's just getting the rest of the form to cooperate.